# Can I reset a conversation in Mass effect 2

Tags: mass-effect-2

so I was doing a second play through of Mass effect, and since this was going to be fem shep renegade, I was dead set on romancing Garrus, but I botched the conversation that led to that romance and didn't realize this until about 7 hours of gameplay later. is there a way to reset the conversation you have with Garrus after his loyalty mission through the binary files or something of that nature so that I don't have to sink another 35 hours into ME2 to fix this.

Comment: save editor is your friend

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no way of doing that besides reloading a previous save. There are cheats that allow you to [quick-save before a conversation](http://www.nightsolo.net/games/masseffect2/hints.html), but there's little you can do after the conversation has occurred.

Alternatively, you may edit the 'binary files' with a [save editor](http://social.bioware.com/project/4373/). However, the tables for ME2 doesn't seem to be as clear as for ME3, so while there might not be a way to reset a specific conversation, you can directly edit the romanced or alive/dead values. Just follow this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw/zv8mxcxs) (and maybe [this thread](http://social.bioware.com/project/4373/discussion/78600/) too) that shows you exactly which values you need to edit with the save editor.

Comment: More like, in that page full of tweaks, there's a _tip_ to _quick-save before any conversation_.